# Block or allow websites with "/etc/hosts" is really deprecated? What to use instead?

Tags: java, linux, http, ubuntu, proxy

I'm creating a Java project for my university and one of the features of my project is to block / allow websites that was set by the teacher (it's an open-source laboratory monitoring software). **Actually I need something easier:** block ALL sites but allow only a few (allow about 2 or 3 sites, all the others must be blocked).

I've found [this excellent tutorial](https://jamalahmed.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/using-etchosts-allow-and-etchosts-deny-to-secure-unix/) that uses `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` to do exactly what I need. However [I discovered that these files and this method of blocking / allowing websites is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/a/23225/145168).

I don't think IPTables is a good way to achieve my aim, because to allow the access to a single website I need allow an IP address - but remember that a single hostname can have several IP addresses (like any Google service, Facebook and even Moodle of my university).

#### So, what would be the best way to block all websites and allow only a few?

Comment: How is this, specifically, related to Java or a Java app? Anyway, you can look at older projects like NISTNet.

Comment: @jdv Java is just the way we (I'm member of that project) will manage the blocking list. Using IPTables, we will probably call IPTables using the Runtime class of Java. Using /etc/hosts, we will probably edit /etc/hosts using Java's File class. And so on. Btw, thanks for the link, i'll see if it can helps.

Comment: iptables is the best way.  It is not a good way (from your perspective), but it is still the best ... if you are looking for a free / mainstream solution.  Now in a commercial world you would at this point start looking at the various products produced by "security solution" vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that IPtables uses IP addresses rather than DNS addresses is that it is relatively easy for the bad guys to block or spoof a DNS server, and thereby evade the blocks that you have put in place.

The best way *is* to use iptables (or the equivalent) *because* they block based on IP addresses.

---

> I don't think IPTables is a good way to achieve my aim, because to allow the access to a single website I need allow an IP address - but remember that a single hostname can have several IP addresses (like any Google service, Facebook and even Moodle of my university).

IPTables will happily allow (or block) multiple IP addresses belonging to a single service.  You have to *tell* it what those IP addresses are, but once you've done that, it will allow / block them.

And in fact, that is the heart of the firewall management problem.  There is **no way of knowing**:

- what IP addresses Facebook (say) are going to use, or
- if an IP that Facebook previously used is still (notionally) used by Facebook, or
- if someone has hijacked a Facebook IP address.

DNS cannot be relied on to answer any of these questions.  Facebook don't need to advertise their IP addresses in DNS because they don't need to rely on DNS lookup.  And *they* probably won't know if one of their hosts has been hijacked.

---

You also ask if blocking or allowing websites with "/etc/hosts.allow" and "/etc/hosts.deny" is really deprecated.

Well, it depends on what you mean by "deprecated".  When I run "man hosts.allow" on my (Fedora 20) Linux box, it doesn't mention the word "deprecated", and when I Google "hosts.allow deprecated", I don't see anything credible.  (Hint: it is unwise to treat SO answers as being authoritative.)

My understanding of "deprecated" for software is that it means that the supplier recommends that you stop using it.  I see no sign that this has occurred.

However, the "hosts.allow" approach (or more precisely, "tcpd(8)") does have its limitations.  Quoting from ["HOWTO - Limiting Access to TCP-wrapped Services with hosts.allow"](http://static.closedsrc.org/articles/dn-articles/hosts_allow.html)

> *"Hosts.allow is quite an interesting and useful facility that can help increase the security of the host, but typos and poorly written rules can make the host as or more susceptible to exploits than without those rules. Typos could also end up locking yourself out of the box when you least expect it. As stated above, using the access control facility for "TCP wrapped" services and daemons can and probably will take a hit on the host's performance and possibly limit the response rate for the client."*
>
> *"The facility is not a complete security solution nor should it be treated as such, **rather it's a compliment to packet filtering and firewall solutions available** (be it gratis, free-speech or commercial). There are some features that are available only by using the hosts.allow facility such as redirecting specific clients to other services, or returning specific error messages, and banners specific to the service and/or client. Nonetheless, this is a great facility that some people overlook as a method to provide a simple means to deny access to specific services to specific hosts."*

It is also with noting that the source article for that HOWTO is rather dated.  It was written in 2002, and a lot has changed since then.

Finally, note that if you put DNS names into your "hosts.allow" and "hosts.deny" files, you open yourself up to the problems I explained above.

Comment: Hey. IPTables cannot block efficiently distributed services like Facebook.com and similars, because they're....distributed, and by distributed they have multiple IPs, **as explained in the question**. How you would solve something like that by using IPTables? (Remember that using something like 150.162.*.* is not an option too because they will allow access to too much things).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as @FernandoMota commented, this don't solve the problem that I've specified in the question. This don't solve the problem with distributed services like Facebook, Google and others. Sorry, but I can't give you best answer, since you suggested a thing that will not work.

Comment: But if you can suggest a script to do these needs with IPTables (solving the problem of distributed services too), I would be glad and of course will give you the best answer.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini Such a script probably will not work correctly because it will need to watch DNS changes in the domain you want to block. And, if I can remember correctly, its possible to DNS to change from PC to PC, because of the use of technologies like [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast), for example...

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, @FernandoMota

Comment: Well, you give a nice answer now (thanks for the text). This didn't help me at all, but you probably take a lot of time writing this answer and this explains some things about `/etc/hosts` file, so I give you the best answer.